# Libgdx audio playing

Tags: android, audio, libgdx

I use code above to play an audio file.

```
    sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/main_sound.mp3"));
    sound.loop(.5f);
```

It has been worked in Eclipse, but now I use Android Studio and it doesn't play audio file. This happens without any error message.

Comment: Make sure your file name is EXACTLY same as "main_sound.mp3". If you used any capitals in file name, for example "Main_Sound.mp3", java won't be able to locate file after you deploy your application even though it would work without errors in eclipse.

Comment: It is with same name in assets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import `com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music` class instead of `com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound`.

It will working perfectly.